# Implement repeating behaviors with numerous amount but same html elements

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say we have a group of HTML element like this [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/65Q9L/) with certain behaviors. Having one of this is easy on a HTML page.

But what is the best practice of having 1000 of them (the same JS fiddle) on a page? This is not only about dynamically generating required HTML elements but more importantly **generating the behaviors/JS codes** for each individual element (with different values and id).

An Example:

```
document.getElementById("ID1").onchange = function () {
 //some complicated behaviors
};
```

Generate the a ID2/ID3/ID4...ID1000 version of the above codes in run time when needed. Note that it must be running on HTML environment with no servers. Select options/data are stored in the same html file (as an array or some sort).

Any advice or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, rather than loading up all the possible options in the DOM, you would use AJAX to fetch the next set of options from the server. So when you select the state, it goes and grabs the counties for that state, then when you select the county, it goes and grabs the cities for that state.

To go further, when you select the state, it sends the selected state back to the server to fetch all the counties for that state. Then when you select the county, it sends that back to the server so it can fetch the cities.

You can use the server side language of your choice of course (PHP, ASP.net, Ruby, Python, etc.)

Otherwise, you're injecting a ton of data in to your DOM that will never get used and that would vastly increase load times; whereas AJAX is generally pretty fast.

There are lots of tutorials regarding the use of AJAX so I'm not going to cover that in the answer, but that is your best solution.

Comment: @Disfster The JS fiddle is just an example. The condition I am in is that I cannot have a server in place. All the selection data must be stored in the same html file.

Comment: If there's no server, where is the HTML coming from in the first place? It's got to be loaded up from somewhere? But without AJAX then your only choice is to load it all in to the DOM. Maybe load it up as JSON and parse it out using javascript? That depends. But it's a poor implementation to do it that way.

Comment: It is loaded locally as a HTML page. And the server is in a very closed environment that one cannot retrieve data from it but only POST something to it.

Comment: By the way, the possible select options are not numerous. The number of elements are instead very huge.

Comment: Well, the HTML files have to be coming from the server in the first place. You POST the state and retrieve the counties, etc. Otherwise, like I said, you have to load everything up in the DOM from the get go and that's ugly.

Comment: If we have to do it in the ugly way, what about generating new codes in run time?

Comment: New elements you mean? Well, then it might be best to store all the data in javascript arrays and then parse them in to the elements as needed. Otherwise you end up with a complex system of hide/unhide that becomes unmanageable.

Comment: I mean codes that control behaviors of newly generated elements which I think is more complex than generating elements.

Comment: Well, when you add elements dynamically, it's a little extra work to control them but with a sensible naming convention and well structured functions, it's managable.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged the questions only with Javascript so I assume that you have the data locally and you don't retrieve it from a server.If you take the data from the server use Ajax and get only the data that you need at that moment.

With Javascript you can use

```
document.createElement('element'); // this is faster than Jquery if you generate a lot of data
```

with Jquery you can use

```
$(document.createElement('element'))
```

Comment: Creating elements is easy. The difficult part is getting the required behaviors of newly generated elements in place through generating new codes in run time.

Comment: @Tim1234 You mean how you generate document.getElementById("ID1").for all ID# ?

Comment: @Tim1234 Make a function that takes as input a value and then create the string "ID" + value  and the getElementById will search for that string and you just change the function value to change the behavior